# How do I enable a greyed out toggle to enable install from unknown sources on a Moto g power (2021)?

Tags: motorola

I have a Moto g power (2021) upon attempting to install a non-market app I was given the whole 'for your security your phone is not allowed to install from unknown sources' and the option to go to settings and enable it is there at the bottom. But the toggle is greyed out. How can I enable this?

Comment: Where did you got the phone from (new device from shop, from employer, friend, ..), is there an Mobile Device Management (MDM) solution installed or is the device managed in some way?

Comment: I bought it 2nd hand on a buy and sell it came factory reset

Comment: Have you performed a factory rest on your own? Without I would not recommend to use a used phone no matter how clean it looks. This is also recommended to check if FRP or other MDM protection is triggered by a factory reset.

Comment: Funny you should say that because it was frp locked....I fixed that issue but I justcan't seem to enable install from unknown sources

Comment: Then most likely the phone is a stolen one and still managed by an MDM. Sorry but we won't help you with making a stolen phone work.

Comment: I was assured the device was not stolen ; the gentleman who sold it to me was locked out of his Google account and was having the worst luck trying to get back in

Comment: That sounds even more dodgy!

Comment: What you never been locked out of an account before? CRA ; GOOGLE ; FB , the list goes on... I have so I sympathised with the dude. Besides the device works just fine I'm sorry if I offended your moral compass , Geez!

Comment: You didn't offend. It's just that the "I got locked out" and "my aunt just dies and all I got was this lousy phone" are the most used excuses when someone wants to sell a device obtained from its owner without consent. So even if it might be true, it smells. Unfortunately, those doing that "daily" sound the most convincing… Guess the seller also got locked out from where the bill from buying the device was stored, right? And the original box was lost? Whichever, I'm afraid we cannot even help you as we don't know what MDM might be in use etc.

Comment: Not a problem - I get it. And you're right ; when you put it like that it does sound a bit sketchy. -thing is , I never really gave it much thought, especially since I encounter devices that are blacklisted and/or frp locked on a daily basis ; it's a bottomless market and I can't imagine every one of those devices was ' 'accidentally  locked ' or whatever excuse of the day may be. I  was really just curious about why the toggle  to install from unknown sources was greyed out, that's all I didn't realize how above board and by the book everyone on this forum was,. - my bad.